# ServiceBus WorkerRole DiagnosticMonitor Error

Tags: azure, azureservicebus

I have a WebRole and 2 ServiceBus WorkerRoles running, During the OnStart of the roles I get the following 
Exception: **[System.ArgumentOutOfRangeException] invalid syntax for container log4net Parameter name: initialConfiguration**

```
Running Azure:  
ConfigurationManager version=1.7.0.3  
ServiceBus version=1.7.0.1  
Storage version=1.7.0.0
```

This occurs while running locally in the dev Azure environment and in the Cloud. All roles have the following Configurtion settings:

```xml
<LocalStorage name="Log4Net" cleanOnRoleRecycle="true" sizeInMB="2048" />
```

All Roles have the following code in the OnStart:

```cs
try
{
     // Configure Diagnostics to poll Log file to Blob Storage
     var diagnosticsConfig = DiagnosticMonitor.GetDefaultInitialConfiguration();
     diagnosticsConfig.Directories.ScheduledTransferPeriod = TimeSpan.FromMinutes(5);
     diagnosticsConfig.Directories.DataSources.Add(
         new DirectoryConfiguration
             {
                 Path = RoleEnvironment.GetLocalResource("Log4Net").RootPath,
                 DirectoryQuotaInMB = 512,
                 Container = "wad-WebRolelog4net"
             });
     DiagnosticMonitor.Start("Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Plugins.Diagnostics.ConnectionString", diagnosticsConfig);  
}
catch
{
        OnStop();
        return false;
}
```

**Stack Trace:**

> at Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Diagnostics.DiagnosticMonitorConfiguration.Validate(String paramName, Nullable`1 resourceSize)
>      at Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Diagnostics.DiagnosticMonitor.StartWithExplicitConfiguration(DiagnosticMonitorStartupInfo startupInfo, DiagnosticMonitorConfiguration initialConfiguration)
>      at Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Diagnostics.DiagnosticMonitor.Start(CloudStorageAccount storageAccount, DiagnosticMonitorConfiguration initialConfiguration)
>      at Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Diagnostics.DiagnosticMonitor.Start(String diagnosticsStorageAccountConfigurationSettingName, DiagnosticMonitorConfiguration initialConfiguration)
>      at CICRMIntegrationQueue.WorkerRole.OnStart() in c:\Projects\Client\Connection Intelegence\CICloud\CICRMIntegrationQueue\WorkerRole.cs:line 193

This error seems to occur when I have a local storage and `DiagnosticMonitor` polling in all 3 roles, when only one is defined the error does not occur.

Comment: What is the value of **DirectoryConfiguration.Path** - `RoleEnvironment.GetLocalResource("Log4Net").RootPath`?

Comment: C:\Users\.....\AppData\Local\dftmp\Resources\1e237395-fc90-4195-b364-1b25b2e5d2d9\directory\log4net\
C:\Users\....\AppData\Local\dftmp\Resources\33334164-d293-447a-a9a2-bf484ed63ac2\directory\log4net\

Comment: Found it, my fault inializing Diagnostics twice.